# C preprocessor statement

Tags: c

I was going through some open source code and stumbled upon this below statement. Can someone knowledgeable in C help me what actually it means?

```
#define SYSTEM_CURRENT_USER (1 << 16)
```

Comment: [Google would have helped you faster](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=%22%23define%22%20c&es_th=1).

Comment: On a system where `int` is only 16 bits, it actually has undefined behavior (or rather, any use of the macro has undefined behavior). If that's a concern, writing `0x10000` avoids the problem, since constants (unlike constant expressions) have whatever type is needed to hold their value. But depending on the environment, it's possible that `int` being less than 32 bits isn't worth worrying about.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it's trivially Googleable.

Answer (score 2):

It defines a value `SYSTEM_CURRENT_USER` assigned the value of 1 shifted to the left by 16 bits, which is 65536.

Answer (score 2):

It's defining a constant bitmask value.  It's equivalent to

```
#define SYSTEM_CURRENT_USER 65536
```

or

```
#define SYSTEM_CURRENT_USER 0x10000
```

Presumably someone thought it was more readable to define with the left-shift operator, emphasizing that it's bit 16 (17?) that's set in the mask.

Comment: +1 for bit mask, the actual value of the operation doesn't matter. The location of the `1` in the bit mask does.

Answer (score 0):

In C, << is the left shift operator. So, this is defining the "SYSTEM_CURRENT_USER" as 1 shifted left 16 bits I believe.